# Getting 'matches' array data within a 'query' from an API and displaying the information

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api

I am having trouble displaying data from querying an API endpoint. The error message is `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. I understand that I have to jump to display the "matches" array but having a lot of difficulty doing so.

This is what the url returns:

```
    {
      "query": "An",
      "matches": [
         {"name": "Jane Hardman", "id": "248086622848468681706182205280565550732"}, 
         {"name": "Gary Aldan", "id": "246529435182620212343890064029443600078"}
      ]
    }
```

This is my `meeting-handler.service.ts` file:

```
constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getListOfEmployees(query: string = '') {
    return this._httpClient.get(
      `${this.meetingUrl}/employees?q=${query}`);
  }
```

This is my `meeting-form.component.ts` file:

```
export class MeetingFormComponent implements OnInit {
  employees;

  constructor(private _meetingService: MeetingHandlerService) { 
    this._meetingService.getListOfEmployees('An').subscribe(
      res => this.employees = res
    )
  }
```

And finally this is my `meeting-form.component.html` file:

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees"></div>
    <p>{{ employee.name }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    <p>{{ employee.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Moved the closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` is inside `this.employees.matches` and you have to iterate on the `matches` field.

Can you try this :

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees?.matches.name"></div>
    <p>{{ employee }}</p>
```

---

Can you try to edit your get request ?

```
return this.http.get(`${this.meetingUrl}/employees`, {
  params: new HttpParams()
    .set('q', query)
})
```

---

I checked your stackblitz and I found a typo here :

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees?.matches.name"></div>
<p>{{ employee.name }}</p>
```

Why are you using `{{ employee.name }}` ? You iterate on **name** so you employee is already a `name`.

Try this :

```
<div *ngFor="let name of employees?.matches.name"></div>
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

Comment: Tried it. Am not getting any console errors although no information is being displayed. A step in the right direction I think.

Comment: Can you display the content of `this.employees` ?

Comment: I typed this.employees in the chrome console and it returns `undefined`.

Comment: If you cannot display the `this.employee` in your console, it is probably mean you have an error with your request. Did you test your endpoint? With Postman or something else?

Comment: tested it now with Postman. Endpoint is working fine and returning data with my key as q and value as 'an'. Im thinking that I should be defining some sort of "matches" params within the GET function? Have never worked with defining params in Angular though...

Comment: I edited my answer with it. Try to display in the console your `this.employees` after the change.

Comment: Imported HttpParams from common but I'm still in the same position. this.employee returns the json same as before. Although thanks for mentioning it. Something new to learn.

Comment: this.employees returns undefined*

Comment: `this._meetingService.getListOfEmployees('An').subscribe(res => console.log(res))` returns something?

Comment: It does. With your code the import the call is being made and my network tab is showing the query and the matches.

Comment: I am out of solutions.. Can you provide a little stackblitz to check the code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be5trw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css if you would like to have a go

Comment: Is any information being displayed for you? If I change employee to name there is no ouptut for the employee of employees.

Comment: Seems you're just returning the name value from the app component.